# How should I structure a multi env app in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.6

So here's my "problem". I already have a website that can welcome users. But now, I want to make another layer (as we can call it) over my current web app to enable many other people to buy my web app. I'm wondering how I could change my app so when someone subscribes a new league on it that it creates a database and some new routes automatically for his league.

Let's say i'm a new guy subscribing to my app. I subscribe my league as "aLeague". Now, my goal is to get some paths like: www.mydomain.com/aLeague/...

How could I structure this? Should I make many .env? How can I create new path automatically for new created routes?

Answer (score 1):

You are describing [Multitenancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy)

You can either build your own or use currently available solutions:

1. https://laravel-tenancy.com/
2. https://github.com/tenancy/multi-tenant

Comment: I've seen that the requirements are laravel 5.8, but i'm using Laravel 5.6 :( Is there a way I can use it with 5.6?

Comment: @ettdro Search for "laravel multi tenant" to look at what options are available. I would suggest upgrading to 5.8 https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade

Comment: Yeah, I'll try to upgrade Laravel to 5.8 as you say! Thanks, I'll give you feedback